# TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsPlumb' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jsplumb, angular-gantt

I need help please, I can't use dependency between tasks in angular-gantt. I found this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsPlumb' of undefined
    at new DependenciesManager (http://localhost:8080/....

HTML file code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12"
                 gantt data=gantEventsData
                 from-date="ganttOptions.fromDate"
                 to-date="ganttOptions.toDate"
                 view-scale="ganttOptions.scale"
                 headers="ganttOptions.headers"
                 current-date="ganttOptions.currentDate"
                 max-height="ganttOptions.maxHeight"
                 side-width = "ganttOptions.sideWidth"
                 allow-side-resizing="ganttOptions.allowSideResizing" >
                <gantt-dependencies></gantt-dependencies>
                <gantt-tree></gantt-tree>
            </div>
```

The dependencies object in package.json

```
"{
  "_from": "jsplumb@2.3.2",
  "_id": "jsplumb@2.3.2",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha1-onPSUrbOhRakECj8mdzGSKKct7g=",
  "_location": "/jsplumb",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "version",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "jsplumb@2.3.2",
    "name": "jsplumb",
    "escapedName": "jsplumb",
    "rawSpec": "2.3.2",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "2.3.2"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "Visual connectivity for webapps",
  "devDependencies": {
    "biltong": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-yuidoc": "0.5.2",
    "grunt-exec": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-jekyll": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-qunit-junit": "^0.3.1",
    "jsbezier": "^0.9.1",
    "katavorio": "^0.19.2",
    "morgan": "1.8.0",
    "mottle": "^0.8.0"
  },

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question does not contain enough information which allows us to help you. Consider adding some more data, It whould be great to create a small reproducible example on https://stackblitz.com. Please, take a look at this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you have jsPlumb installed? What do you have in the dependencies section of package.json?

Comment: Yes I installed it, I add a part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is not loaded. Try just to put `<script src="node_modules/jsplumb/dist/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>` on top of the loaded `node_modules` scripts